# convert a very large array of integers into single integer

Tags: c

I found following code on stack exchange blog which converts an array of integers into a single integer. But when my input integer array is more than 10 entries then it fails. Actually i have an array of binary numbers of 32 entries. I want to convert this array into a single binary number. I was trying to use below code but it fails for more than 10 entries. Please suggest a method to accomplish this.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int n;
    int i;
    char buff[100];
    int x[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        sprintf(&buff[i],"%d",x[i]);
    }
    n = atoi(buff);

    printf("the number is %d",n);

}
```

Comment: A 32-bit int isn't large enough to hold a number greater than 2**31-1. Use a long long int, or just print out the digits directly from `x[]`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you can drop `int x[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6};`and the `for` loop and write directly `char buff[] = "0123456";`

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage  I want to keep all 32 bits in a single variable then how can i do this. I can print all numbers from the array but i want to process it further hence want them in a single variable.

Comment: Can you clarify this: `Actually i have an array of binary numbers of 32 entries.` ? Perhaps an example. Does it mean that each entry holds either `0` or `1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do the equivalent for base 2.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int n;
    int i;
    char buff[100];
    int x[]={0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,
             0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,
             1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0};

    n = 0;
    for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
        n = n << 1 + x[i];
    }

    printf("The number is %d in decimal\n", n);

}
```